# Unable to include picture file (.jpg) using texlive from terminal under UBUNTU 16.4

Tags: pdftex, texlive, ubuntu, includegraphics

unable to compile Particular statement `\includegraphics [scale=0.08]{IMG1001.jpg}` while trying to run from the terminal under UBUNTU 16.4 LTS. For clarification,  a minimal program and log file is attached herewith

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}


\includegraphics[scale=0.08]{IMG1001.jpg}
\end{document} 
Logfile 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=latex 2020.7.16)  17 AUG 2020 21:45
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**mini.tex
(./mini.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 81 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2016/01/03 v1.0q Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 95.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvips.def
File: dvips.def 2015/12/30 v3.0k Driver-dependent file (DPC,SPQR)
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
) (./mini.aux)
\openout1 = `mini.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.


! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in IMG1001.jpg (no BoundingBox)
.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 \includegraphics[scale=0.08]{IMG1001.jpg}
                                             
? x
 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 524 strings out of 493030
 6373 string characters out of 6136260
 57790 words of memory out of 5000000
 4127 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3938 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 25i,1n,19p,1422b,153s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.**strong text**

Program is not running even when I comment all `\usepackage` statements.
```

Comment: Please provide a full minimal example instead of a sniplet like this. Additionally it will probably also be useful to see the full log file of this example. Note that most of what you present in the sniplet is nor relevant for `\includegraphics` (only `graphicx`) so you can start by cleaning that up.

Comment: Minimum program and logfile are attached in revised version, anyway same program run while compile through Texmaker in same UBUNU platform using pdftex.

Comment: You're running latex here, latex does not support jpg only eps. Try pdflatex instead (support image formats: pdf, png, jpg and metapost)

Comment: Additionally your minimal example is incomplete as there is no documentclass

Comment: It is quite surprising to me that this program run through Texmaker where  pdflatex is used. From log file (attached in revised version) it  appears that  pdflatex is also used here while compiling  the same program from the terminal.

Comment: The no boundingbox is a clear indicator that this is latex. If your setup is super super old you can try giving graphicx the pdftex option. But I would run pdflatex manually first, manually via the command line, not texmaker

Comment: Also exactly how do you know texmaker is actually running pdflatex?

Comment: \documentclass[12pt]{article} , In the lower part of Texmaker window, one can see the logfile by clicking message/log. The first line of logfile: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex .2020.7.16) 17 AUG 2020 22:55 . Very recently I install full version of Texlive to solve this problem , but it does not work. do you suggest current  version of pdflatex may solve this problem ? I don't know how to run program directly through pdflatex .

Comment: That is not what the log file you posted says. Exactly what did you install regarding the full version? You're likely to now have two latex installations and texmaker is picking up the wrong version, thus my question as to exactly what you did